# decorating JavaScript promises with errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, es6-promise

Let's say I have a JavaScript function `doWork()` that returns a promise, resolved when the work is done.

In my main business logic, I can easily use it:

```
//main program
doWork()
.then(foo => {
  //do something when the work is finished
})
.catch(bar => {
  //handle errors
});
```

That was easy.

But let's say I have a `WorkingFlagService` that managing a global flag indicating whether work is currently being performed. (I don't want to build this functionality into the `doWork()` function, because actually there are many similar `doWork()` functions; they shouldn't know about any application "working" flags.) I want to use a `WorkingFlagService.manageWorkingFlag` to "wrap" the calls to `doWork()` so that it can manage the "working" flag. With JavaScript that shouldn't be hard:

```
//main program
WorkingFlagService.manageWorkingFlag(doWork)
.then(foo => {
  //do something when the work is finished
})
.catch(bar => {
  //handle errors
});
```

This `WorkingFlagService.manageWorkingFlag()` method would set the working flag to `true` before work started, and would set the working flag back to `false` after work is finished. That seems to be the tricky part, assuming `doWork()` returns a promise (ignore the `this` subtleties). I understand there is no longer any promise `finally()` method, so I'll have to try to create a workaround.

```
WorkingFlagService.manageWorkingFlag = (doWorkFn)=> {
  this.isWorking = true;
  const workPromise = doWorkFn();
  workPromise
  .then( () => {this.isWorking = false;} )
  .catch( () => {this.isWorking = false;} );
  return workPromise;
}
```

So if I understand this correctly, in the main program `WorkingFlagService.manageWorkingFlag(doWork).then(...)` will continue to work just fine; `WorkingFlagService.manageWorkingFlag()` will be notified when the work is done so that it can unset the working flag, and the main program will also be notified when the work is done so that it can do whatever it needs to do next.

But if `WorkingFlagService.manageWorkingFlag()` calls `workPromise.catch()` before returning the promise, if an error occurs then `WorkingFlagService` will be notified (is order guaranteed?) so that it can turn off the flag. But will this prevent `.catch()` from being called in the main program?

So I think I can distill my confusion down to these questions:

- If I invoke `promise.then()` on the same promise twice with different callbacks, will both callbacks be called when the promise is resolved?
- If I invoke `promise.catch()` on the same promise twice with different callbacks, will both callbacks be called when the promise is rejected?
- If so, is order of callback guaranteed (based upon when the callbacks were "registered")?

I'm specifically interested in these answers in the context of Angular 1.x promises.

Comment: To answer the 3 questions at the bottom: yes, yes, and yes. Here's the relevant [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Guarantees).

Comment: Yay! It's all about knowing where to look. If you could put that in an official answer, I could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I invoke `promise.then(cb)` on the same promise twice with different
>   callbacks, will both callbacks be called when the promise is resolved?

Yes, but as soon as all callbacks executed without throwing errors. Otherwise you will get subsequent `catch(cb)` callbacks called.

> If I invoke `promise.catch()` on the same promise twice with different
>   callbacks, will both callbacks be called when the promise is rejected?

Yes, all `catch(cb)` callbacks **after** `then(cb)` that throws an error.

> If so, is order of callback guaranteed

Yes, see [2.2.6 in Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-36).

Comment: Are you sure this works with Angular 1.5 `$q` promises and `$mdDialog`? Just adding empty `then()` and `catch()` calls to a promise before returning it seems to somehow short-circuit the process and automatically resolve the dialog promise before it closes. I'll update the question.

Comment: Ack, never mind --- I was using `error()` instead of `catch()` (Java wouldn't have even compiled with that problem; I'm just say'in), and that threw an exception in the middle of some nested promise linked whatever and messed up the whole chain. It seems to be working now.